# How to enter properties as arguments to mixins

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

Currently I do this

```
mox(first, second)
  {first} second

a
  mox(transition, 0.3s linear all)
```

What I want is to actually call the mixin like

```
mox(transition 0.3s linear all)
```

What would `mox` look like? Note the lack of comma and I also currently get

```
a{transition:0.3s}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
mox()
  arguments

a
  mox transition 0.3s linear all
```

Answer (score 1):

Stylus allows you to use the [`arguments`](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/functions.html#arguments) keyword for functions.  You can iterate over this to get each argument that is passed in.

Comment: So how would mox() look like in my example?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you need to use [**interpolation**](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/interpolation.html).

Instead of doing

```
mox()
  arguments

a
  mox transition 0.3s linear all
```

Try

```
mox(prop, args)
  {prop} args

a
  mox('transition', 0.3s linear all)
```

Result on [*Try Stylus*](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html)

[image: test.png]

You could also omit parentheses

```
mox(prop, args)
  -webkit-{prop} args
  {prop} args

a
  mox 'transition', 0.3s linear all
```